# How to find out which functions are being called in a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, profiling

I have CamerSampleSDK.exe C++ application which is using CameraSDK.dll. By unknown reasons company decided not to provide CamerSampleSDK.exe source code to all users who bought their camera. The main question is it possible somehow to find out which functions from CameraSDK.dll application CamerSampleSDK.exe is calling? Which application can be used in this case?

Comment: Yes, assuming they're statically linked it's quite easy: google for `pedump` or `exedump` utilities.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError _dll_ and _exe_ indicate Windows OS, which means dynamic linking.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError can these utilities see which functions the .exe is actually calling? I know that you can see which functions the dll has...

Comment: Dynamic linking, indeed. Your point?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError _"assuming they're statically linked"_ that's my point.

Comment: They can see which functions the exe has references to, but not whether they're actually called - you'll need a debugger/trace utility to determine that for your specific scenario.

Comment: Ah, sorry. That was a typo, and a serious one at that: I meant assuming they're statically _loaded_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit complicated when you don't know functions prototypes and them parameters. But you try to do a small research:

1. Find all functions names which your DLL is exporting (Your target is DLL export table). You can use 'PE Tools' application: open your DLL in PE Editor, 'Directories' -> 'Export directory'. You will see functions names and them addresses:

[image]

2. If you can use IDA Pro, it will be better solution. Try to disassemble your DLL, explore each exported function and deduce parameters types and result by decompiled code. It is more complicated thing in research, you need knowledge of assembler, system architect and machine codes.
3. If you're familiar with debuggers like WinDBG, OllyDBG or another Windows usermode debugger, try to debug application which uses DLL: put breakpoints on each DLL exported function. Check that deduced signatures are correct and find correct call order
4. Try to use DLL in your project with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress and correspond to deduced parameters and call order.